# ajax get dropdown dependent values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am just a newbie in `php,jquery and ajax`.I want to fetch the `state and city name` from the `country name` from database. I have my database is something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propertylocator` (
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `propertylocator` (`store_id`, `store_name`,  `country_name`,  `state_name`, `city_name`, `address`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'My property1',  'India', 'uttar pradesh',  'Ghaziabad', 'Pilkhuwa, Uttar Pradesh 245304, India', 'this is demo test','this is dummy description'),
(2, 'My new Property',  'India', 'Maharashtra', 'Thane', 'Kudavali, Maharashtra 421401, India', 'test propery again', 'another dummy property'),
(3, 'Dummy store', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Sharjah',  'Halwan Suburb', 'Al Ghubaiba - Sharjah - United Arab Emirates', 'this is another dummy store','another text with dummy');
```

Now here I have 3 drop downs 
one for `country name`, 2nd for `state name` and another for `city name`.
In `countryname dropdown` I am getting all the `countryname`. But I want that when I will select `country name(lets say india here)` then I will get the dropdown options for state will be `uttar pradesh and Maharashtra` as they both have the countryname is india, and when I will select United Arab Emirates from country list then I will get all the states name whose country name is`United Arab Emirates in the database`. In the same way it will applied for the `cityname`.
For all this stuff I have done `jQuery ajax` like this

```
<label>Please Select Country</label></td><td>
  <div class="country">
   <select id="country" name="country" onchange="selectCountry();">
   <option value="Select">Select</option> 
   foreach($countrylist as $country) {
   <option value="$country['country_name]" id="$country['country_name]">echo $country['country_name]</option>
    }
  </select>
```

and in function `selectCountry()` my code is like this

```
function selectCountry() {
  var state = $('#country').val();
  console.log(state);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "selectstate.php",
    data: { sta : state }
  }).done(function(html) {
    $('#state').html(html);
  })
}
```

in selectstate.php I have my query like this

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(propertylocator) or die(mysql_error());
$sDB = new SelectDb();
$data = $sDB->selectStatesById($_GET['sta']);
foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo "<option value=" . $row->state . ">" . $row->name . "</option>";
}
```

But here I am not getting any results. It is showing 404 not found error. So can someone kindly tell me whats the issue here.

If there is some error in my code then kindly solve it. So that I can understand the code properly. Thanks

**Update**
I have checked the url path and made it more clearly so one can track the problem.

Comment: make sure `url: "../php/selectstate.php",` this path is correct...also use `success` options callback `function` in your `$.ajax` rather than using `.done()`

Comment: 404 not found is preatty clear, as Dipesh said, the path seems to be wrong... maybe you could try the full path with `http://` just to check if everything else is right!

Comment: Use succes function instead of done function in ajax. Also collect the option tags concatenated in a php variable first and at last echo that variable. Check php path too...

Comment: I have checked the path its fine....but I am not getting any results how?

Comment: the path is not fine !! as @reyaner said, the error message is clear ! Check if your php file and your the file in wich you have your `ajax and html` code are in the same location, in order to perform `url: "selectstate.php"`.

Comment: As everybody mentioned, you hit the wrong page. Absolute directory path in ajax call would do the trick, or if your caller file and callee are located in different directories, you need to adjust URL in ajax accordingly `'../selectstate.php'` or `'anotherdir/selectstate.php'`

Comment: @DipeshParmar - `done` method is fine, it replaces the depricated `success` callback after jquery v 1.9, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is make a call when country drop down value changes to jquery ajax to fetch all the states for selected country and fill the drop down and add it to your html. Then same follow process to call cities for selected state.

Answer (score 0):

url => is path to locate file selectstate.php

```
function selectCountry() {
  var state = $('#country').val();
  console.log(state);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url+"selectstate.php",
    data: { sta : state },
    success: function(html) {    
         $('#state').html(html);
        }
  });
}
```

`.success()` only gets called if your webserver responds with a 200 OK HTTP header - basically when everything is fine.

The callbacks attached to `done()` will be fired when the deferred is resolved

This may help someone